# Couldn't upgrade Ubuntu

Tags: dpkg, debconf

After recover /var/lib/dpkg/status I couldn't upgrade my ubuntu system.

Log is here:

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up debconf (1.5.58ubuntu2) ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
dpkg: error processing package debconf (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 debconf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Could you please coordinate me in fixing the issues. 
I tried everything that I was able find in google, but result is same. 
Thank you advance for help.

so after

```
dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'
```

I have:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
+++-=======================================-==========================================-============-===============================================================================
rF  debconf                                 1.5.58ubuntu2                              all          Debian configuration management system
iU  debconf-i18n                            1.5.58ubuntu2                              all          full internationalization support for debconf
```

If I try :

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

I have :

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of debconf-i18n:
 debconf-i18n depends on debconf (= 1.5.58ubuntu2); however:
  Package debconf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package debconf-i18n (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 debconf-i18n
```

Force install (Method 2):

```
dpkg: error processing package debconf-i18n (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 debconf
 debconf-i18n
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Method 3

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 220 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up debconf (1.5.58ubuntu2) ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
dpkg: error processing package debconf (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of debconf-i18n:
 debconf-i18n depends on debconf (= 1.5.58ubuntu2); however:
  Package debconf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package debconf-i18n (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 debconf
 debconf-i18n
```

Comment: Please show `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`  edit your question for output.

Comment: What is the output of `apt list --installed | grep python` and `echo $PYTHONHOME $PYTHONPATH`?

Answer (score 0):

```
wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/debconf/debconf_1.5.58ubuntu2_all.deb
```

Try to install it directly with

```
sudo dpkg -i debconf_1.5.58ubuntu2_all.deb
```

if this works

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to reconfigure dpkg (Method 1)

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Use force install (Method 2)

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Try removing the troublesome package (Method 3)

```
sudo apt remove
```

Let me know if above methods works!

Comment: Method 2 ain't a force method. It rather attempts to install unmet dependencies, if there

Comment: yeah kind of!........